# Do the Latin words rēs/rēx have the "speech" meaning?

Tags: etymology

In the Old Slavonic there is only one meaning of the word рѣчь (rech') "speech" but in the Polish there are two meanings "speech" and "thing".

In my opinion, the second meaning of the Polish word inherired since the beginning of the 1569 year, when the [Rzeczpospolita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish%E2%80%93Lithuanian_Commonwealth) was established, and only by analogy with latin rēs "thing" + pūblica.

Is it acceptable to argue, that the latin word "rēs" also has the "speech" meaning and that the latin word "rēx" also means the man, who has a right "to speak" (has a voice in) or that man to whose speak all other people are to obey.

In accordance to bible, the God is a Word (speech) and there is none good (well) but one, that is, God.

Jn 1:1:

> "In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God"

Mt 19:17:

> "there is none good but one, that is, God"

Answer (score 12):

First of all, it's worth noting that the words *rēx* and *rēs* are unrelated: *rēx* goes back to PIE `*h₃reǵs` "king" from `*h₃r-ǵ-` "just" (compare *rectus*, *rogō*, *rēgula*), while *rēs* goes back to PIE `*reh₁is` "goods" from `*r-h₁y-` (compare Sanskrit *raí* "property").

*Rēs* is a very general-purpose word, so I wouldn't be surprised to hear it applied to speech. Its basic meaning is "thing" but it's also applied to everything from a system of government to a historical narrative to the current state of reality. In an expression like *rem hanc dixit* "she said this thing" it would clearly mean a statement or utterance.

I would also often translate *rēs* into Greek as *lógos*, literally "word", which is the same word used in the Gospel of John. However, in the phrase *rēspublica* it's definitely **not** referring to an act of speaking: there it has the meaning of "political system", same as in *rēs nova* "revolution". *Rēs* itself never reached Polish on its own (*rēspublica* was borrowed as a single unit), so if its descendant means "speech" in Polish it's a coincidence.

*Rēx*, on the other hand, seems to have no meanings that don't pertain to rulership. It means "king" all the way back as far as we can reconstruct into PIE, never with any meaning related to speech. King, tyrant, (metaphorically) high priest, ruling over something, master, lord, but never "one who speaks" or anything like that.

---

P.S. All of this is concerned with Classical Latin rather than Church Latin; in Christianity, words like *verbum* are almost always used instead of *rēs* to refer to speech. Similarly, *rēx* in Christianity always has the literal meaning of "king": see 1 Timothy 6:15's *rēx rēgum*, "king of kings". So it's safe to say the Bible had little to no impact on either of these words referring to speaking.

Comment: Does Greek ῥῆμα have any relation to *res*? It seems the most obvious parallel to me, and I believe it has the same thing/word range of meaning.

Comment: @brianpck Ooh, interesting thought! Seems not, though. As best I can tell, *rēma* is a *-ma* noun from *eirō* "to say", which used to have a digamma in front of it, so its Latin cognate would be _verbum_.

Comment: Is it *rex regium* or *rex regum*?

Comment: @egreg I've found online versions of the Vulgate saying both; I used *regium* because I vaguely remember the *-ium* ending being more common in Church Latin (even though Classical would use *-um*), but that's a random recollection, not any solid evidence. Is _rex regum_ better-attested?

Comment: Well, an ngram search on English literature shows no trace of *rex regium*, similarly for other corpora.

Comment: @egreg That's pretty solid evidence! I'll edit the answer; _rex regium_ is most likely a transcription error then.

Comment: Google books is never solid evidence of anything. The OCR severely fails for old manuscripts, and it doesn't index anything beyond 1500. jsyk

Comment: This gloss for \*h3r-'g- might be misleading; its correct interpretation is in fact debatable, and we can't reconstruct "king" for PIE because we are not aware of any PIE king (though Kurgan mounts imply powers). There's *oro* "talk", *orate*, etc. assigned \*h2er-, though it's well known that \*h3 is the o-colouring laryngeal. Wiktionary also says in what looks like an edit conflict, that *oro* is from *os, orus* "mouth; head, etc" (from \*h3eh2os), period(!), from \*h2er-. It's complicated. Don't say it isn't. It's not clear what Polish had to do with it.

Comment: @vectory An etymological connection somewhere between _rex_ and _oro_ isn't impossible, but enough Classical Latin literature survives that we can be quite confident about what the words meant by that time. We can also say quite confidently that there are many clear descendants of *_h₃rēǵs_ meaning "king" in disparate branches of IE, and no clear descendants meaning "speaker". Whether the different PIE roots are connected may be an open question, but what those roots' descendants mean generally is not.

Answer (score 3):

To back him up, it should also be noted that the original Greek of John 1:1 goes like:

> Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ **Λόγος**, καὶ ὁ **Λόγος** ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν, καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ **λόγος.**
> *En arche en ho* ***Logos***, *kai ho* ***Logos*** *en pros ton Theōn, kai Theos en ho* ***Logos***.

and 1 Tim 6:15 goes like:

> ἣν καιροῖς ἰδίοις δείξει ὁ μακάριος καὶ μόνος δυνάστης, 
>   ὁ **βασιλεὺς τῶν βασιλευόντων** καὶ κύριος τῶν κυριευόντων, 
>   *hen kairois idiois deixei ho Makarios kai monos dunastos, ho* ***basileus ton basileuonton*** *kai kurios ton kurieuonton,*

These words in their original (here boldened) language clearly have no relation.

Comment: Just so I am clear, Koine ο is rounder than ω, and η is wider, closer to a Latin ē, than ε, which is more short, right?

Comment: In classical Attic, ω η are long and fairly open, ο ε are short and fairly closed, ου ει are long and fairly closed. In Koine, I _believe_ the height distinction had already vanished, so all that was left was ω η long vs ο ε short (and ου ει fully raised).

Comment: You seem to have gotten the macrons the other way around - they indicate length, not vowel closeness, so ο is transcribed as o, ω as ō, ε as e and η as ē.  There might be some long alphas, iotas and ypsilons in there - for these a dictionary should be consulted.